# How to add corrected URL when I can't comment?

Tags: support

Looking at this question: [Change of system of coordinates for the stress matrix](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/414988/change-of-system-of-coordinates-for-the-stress-matrix)

The comment by Samuel Weir (first one) [links to a url](https://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Courses/En221/Notes/Polar_Coords/Polar_Coords.htm) that is is not displaying the equations (at least on all of my browsers). I found a [link to the same basic page](http://solidmechanics.org/text/AppendixD/AppendixD.htm) (written by the same author) that is displaying correctly on my computer.

Unfortunately I'm not high enough ranked to comment in the question to say "FYI, if this website isn't working for you, check out this one with the exact same information."

Any idea what I should/can do?

Comment: I've added a comment with the URL you found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since comments are supposed to be transient anyway, you need not do anything, except to possibly flag the comment as *no longer needed* since dead links are rarely needed.

If the information in the comment is a relevant addition to the question or an answer, you might also suggest an edit that adds this information (with the correct link) to the post.

Comment: Gotcha. Does flagging a comment hurt the commenter? I was going to flag, but didn't want to hurt their score.

Comment: @u2berggeist No, flagging comments has no effect on reputation, nor any other ill effects, and we do not hold it against users if they leave comments that later become obsolete.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Presumably this is specific to flags as 'No longer needed', though, right? Flags as rude or abusive should have a (cumulative) effect.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Flags as rude/abusive feed into another system for detecting rude/abusive users or may provoke additional moderator intervention beyond deleting the comment, but the *flag as such* has no deterministic additional effects. (But my answer specifically told the user to flag as *no longer needed* anyway)